# @ControllerAdvice to handle different url error

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, controller-advice

I am making 2 API calls:

```
Response result1 = restTemplate.postForObject(api1url, data1, Response.class);

Response result2 = restTemplate.postForObject(api2url, data2, Response.class);
```

I am using `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle the error if any service is down (505 Unavailable)

So an API is down, I will receive 505 **regardless which API it is**
which I will handle it in `@RestControllerAdvice`. But the problem is I don't know which API is down. I can use try-catch to solve this problem but since overall I am making many API calls this would clutter my code and also I want to ( as practically much I can) to use only `RestControllerAdvice` to handle all exceptions.

My goal is to use `RestControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions specific to each API when it is down

Is there a way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help!

1. Create your own Exception class (Let's say `ApiCallFailedException`)
2. Add members to the class such as `HTTP_CODE, ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_CODE` etc which might be helpful to identify information
3. Throw this `ApiCallFailedException` if any of your API call failed

For e.g.

```
public void apiCallMethod(){
if(callToAPIOneFailed()){
throw new ApiCallFailedException(Http_code,"Message that One API Failed" , error_code);
}
}
```

.. so on for other APIs

4. In your `@RestControllerAdvice` annotated class , define the following

> @ExceptionHandler(value= {ApiCallFailedException.class})
> @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.Internal_server_error)
>
> public void handleApiCallExceptions(Exception ex)
>
> {
>
> // However you define return value or void , but this handler will
> catch your ApiCallFailed exception
>
> }